# ImportError: No module named boilerpipe

Tags: python, virtualenv, boilerpipe

Every time when I call the following code:

```
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
```

I get the error stating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/boilerpipe/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boilerpipe
```

I am calling this code in **virtualenv**. When I call it in my normal environment everything works just fine.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't have that `boilerpipe` installed in the virtualenv. Python is looking in that environments library for the packages and if it's not there it can't load it.

Here is how to check: run `pip show boilerpipe` and see if you get any info about the package.

Here is a sample output from `pip show`:

```
---
Name: boilerpipe
Version: 1.2.0.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: JPype1, charade
```

If you can't see any output then install the package with `pip install boilerpipe` cause you don't have it in your `virtualenv` environment.

If you already have that package in your environment try to reinstall it. First run `pip uninstall boilerpipe` to uninstall any previous installed packages and then `pip install boilerpipe` to install it.